# What "kinds of things are your father" interested in?

Tags: grammar

Which is correct: - "What kinds of things are your father interested in?" or 
"What kinds of things is your father interested in?"

And what is the subject for this question...is it "kinds of things" or "your father"?

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure this must be a duplicate, but if you answer the question by turning it around to make a statement, it becomes

> - My father are interested in ...
> - My father is interested in ...

Obviously only the latter is correct, so the question must use *is* too.

> What kinds of things is your father interested in?

Comment: What if the statement is: "Gardening and carpentry are the kinds of things my father is interested in." Would the question then change to "What kinds of things are your father interested in?"

Comment: No. You still have "my father **is**" in that statement. It is the *is* which goes with *my father.*

Comment: Perhaps to : *What are the kinds of things your father is interested in*. There is a clear difference in the parsing of *What kinds of things is he interested in* and *What are the kind of things he is interested in*. The first is passive voice, the first is active. And the subject changes from *Your father* to *the kind of things*. At least I think that is what is going on, but I would bow to more technical opinion on the matter.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I appreciate it.

I'm wondering what's the subject in the question "What kinds of things is your father interested in?" Isn't it "kinds of things" and not "your father"?

How do we determine the subject in questions? I read from somewhere that "What...?" is usually the subject in questions. Is that true? If it is, then it would make "kinds of things" the subject...and if it is the subject, then I think the verb should follow the subject which is plural in the phrase "kinds of things"...making "What kinds of things are your father interested in?" seem right...